# Creating a smart pointer member of class referencing itself is a elegant design pattern in c++?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, smart-pointers

I would like to know if following code is a good pattern in C++?

There is no problem at all. The code works. But I would like to know if this can lead to some sort of problem.

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
class Class {
    public:
        std::shared_ptr<Class> shared_ptr;

        Class() : shared_ptr(this) {}
        ~Class() { shared_ptr.reset(); }
};
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Automatically create smart pointers as members to generated object.

Comment: You may want to look at this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this

Comment: The downsides to doing what you have in your example, or using the mechanism in the link I provided is that now the objects are self-aware that they are shared_ptr objects.  Which means if you also make non-shared_ptr objects, they may have difficulties if attempting to share ownership of those (say) stack based objects.  To close that door, make the constructors private, and add a factory function -- which is good if the class is final, but if you use it as a base class it gets very awkward quickly.  Also, if the class has a member that has a strong shared_ptr to the object, it'll never die.

Comment: There is a huge problem: this shared pointer just occupies memory without controlling object lifetime. This pointer is just a waste. Also it is public so if some other part of code creates a copy of `shared_ptr` it will be left with a dangling pointer after object goes out of scope.

Comment: *"There is no problem at all. "* - I beg to differ. It's not a good pattern. The name of the member notwithstanding (really? named the same as the template class?) you have an ownership circle that's just itching to invoke UB. Take @Eljay s advice and read how to use shared_from_this. And **seriously** consider what possible problem you are solving by having a self-referencing instance through a shared pointer. Chances are the *real* answer is critical to that unstated problem.

Comment: "Automatically create smart pointers as members to generated object." this is not what you are trying to achieve, this is what you are trying to do to achieve something. So again what are you trying to achieve by having this pointer?

Comment: not sure, but my first thought is that I dislike this for the same reason I dislike the singleton pattern, an object should participate in controlling its own life time

Comment: why is the `Class` a template? Did you mean to use `T` somewhere?

Comment: Where I've seen other developers heavily use `std::shared_ptr` is to mimic life cycle and ownership of other languages, such as Objective-C and Cocoa, or C# and .NET, or Java and JVM.  C++ doesn't use those ownership models, in general (but `std::shared_ptr` is available for those cases when warranted) -- I think it is better to embrace C++ ownership model, and distinguish classes as value-based, identity-based, and service-based.  But that's getting onto a different topic.

Comment: @Slava, automaticaly control lifecycle of a dynamically allocated object, without having to create a smart pointer to archive that for every new object with it own class.

Comment: "automaticaly control lifecycle of a dynamically allocated object."  That what smart pointers do without necessity to store them inside managed object.

Comment: By example. I would like to copy a segment from a buffer and put it into a processing queue detaching it from previous buffer and keeping track of this detached buffer lifecycle. When I do the same process to different classes of buffers I have to build something that I should be reusing.

So, I'm trying to find a pattern to do It properly. So, I am studying smart pointers and their applications, patterns and limits.

Comment: Study is good. Experiments are good. Sometimes what you learn from the study and the experiments that back the study is, "Well... That doesn't work." Keep it up!

Comment: *copy a segment from a buffer*  Alternative: Make a class that manages a "view" of the buffer. At its most primitive it would be a pointer to the start of the data of interest and a length of the range of interest (Edit: And a few management functions to make life easier). No copying of anything required and when you're done with it you can just let it fall out of scope to get rid of it. Use [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) as inspiration. Edit 2: Note that this requires the buffer to not change out from under the view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the code posted is neither useful nor safe.

There are three scenarios, and none of them have a positive result:

1. The object is created in automatic storage

In this case, the object will be destroyed when it goes out of scope.  It's destructor will be run and attempt to free memory it does not own, resulting in undefined behavior.
[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ea3fe01a02f3f33)

2. The object is created in dynamic storage and gets `delete`d by the caller

In this case the destructor will be invoked when the caller (or some smart pointer created by the caller) `delete`s the object.  Your destructor will then try to `delete` the object again, resulting in undefined behavior.
[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c96b78b9e2af3df4)

3. The object is created in dynamic storage and doesn't get `delete`d by the caller

In this case, the object will never be destroyed.  It's destructor will never be invoked, and its storage will be leaked.  Your extra `shared_ptr` member achieved nothing.
[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d1e22a7176d6baf)

Comment: So. The first approach doesn't seems to be acceptable once, smart pointers should be made to manage dinamically allocated objects. The second behaviour seems to be mitigated in the destructor of the class when calling shared_ptr.reset(); The third case at all is the most important. What I would like to archive seems not to be archived. But I would test it and whatch this behaviour.

Comment: @arthur.afarias `shared_ptr.reset();` will cause the shared pointer to try to delete the memory it owns, which is the object itself that's already in the process of being deleted. There is no way to release a `std::shared_ptr` without it deleting what it owns.

Comment: @arthur.afarias In the first scenario, no smart pointers should ever be involved.  Automatic variables have their lifetime managed by scope, and must never be `delete`d, either manually or via a smart pointer.  In the second scenario, `shared_ptr.reset()` is exactly what causes the double free.  `reset` will `delete` the object pointed to if that was the last copy of the `shared_ptr` pointing to it.  The third scenario is what I think you're _trying_ to make work, but it doesn't.  The code creating the object should create a smart pointer to manage it.  The object can't do that on its own.

Comment: Thank you by this description of how this shouldn't work as I expect and why this cannot be done in this way. You explained me verry well and clarified a lot. I'm trying to create some pattern that could generate the object and it's associated smart pointer detached from original dynamically allocated object. But this is another question I should mark this as solved.